# S3 InvalidPolicyDocument token enclosed in quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to forward my file to S3 (POST to the bucket) and can't help but receive the error

```
Invalid Policy: Token - must be enclosed in quotes
```

What can I do about it? What does it even mean? The S3 docs surely don't say anything about it. I would provide the request body, but it contains classified information, so I can't. This is the 400 response in total:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
    <Message>Invalid Policy: Token - must be enclosed in quotes.</Message>
    <RequestId>63CD13067F1E6D45</RequestId>
    <HostId>IupjHWw2xBy34FDTXGW01SKPoOI24G7p66i4gmUWoQslBuqoq/5vcIjoQETYFA4smgVNwAuCyfmk</HostId>
</Error>
```

Not much to go by, I'm afraid. TYIA for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer this myself:
The reason was to be found in the "user" parameter which became an object {ID: -1} when authenticating with token, but remained intact with Cookie-based auth. The solution was to make sure that this parameter is a string.